# Can I have null values in clustering columns of a primary key?

Tags: cassandra

So I have a table and I want to make a composite primary key: one partition key and several clustering columns. However these columns are not strictly speaking always populated, so some rows may have null values. Is this allowed in Cassandra? To have clustering columns with null values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra does not allow null clustering key values.

If you really need "no value" for some reason, then use an empty string OR some other special literal value like 'UNDEFINED' to cluster those together.

A similar question is here:
[How can I have null column value for a composite key column in CQL3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963248/how-can-i-have-null-column-value-for-a-composite-key-column-in-cql3)

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to have `null` values in clustering keys but only in tables created `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` and only for trailing columns.
For example:

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE cf (p int, c1 int, c2 int, v int, primary key (p, c1, c2)) WITH COMPRESSION = {'sstable_compression': ''} AND COMPACT STORAGE;
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO cf (p, c1, v) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM cf;

 p | c1 | c2   | v
---+----+------+---
 1 |  1 | null | 1

(1 rows)
```

In regular (non-compact) tables, clustering keys cannot have missing columns.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Is COMPACT STORAGE the default now? Because it works for me without specifying it.

Comment: No, COMPACT STORAGE is not the default. It is obsolete, and with the introduction of the new SStables format (dubbed 'SSTables 3.0' or SSTables mX) in Cassandra 3.x, has no advantage over regular tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the clustering columns on INSERT, when you pass only STATIC field values. And this makes sense, because static fields relate to the partition itself, not to the partition rows (identified by the clustering keys).

This helps implementing one-to-many parent-child relationships within a partition, as in the following example (tested on Amazon Keyspaces and DSE DB 4 Astra):

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
   country text,
   country_pop int STATIC,
   state text,
   state_pop int,
   PRIMARY KEY (country, state)
);

INSERT INTO countries (country, country_pop) VALUES ('USA', 328000000);
```

Comment: You can't skip clustering column when you inserting the data - you *must* provide full primary key. You can skip "ordinary" columns yes.  The only exception for that case is when you have static columns, and you inserting partition key + static columns without clustering columns

Comment: I know what their doc says, but I just repro-ed it on Amazon Keyspaces. Try it, it works! :)

Comment: it's a problem of Amazon Keyspaces, that isn't the real Cassandra... I checked with real Cassandra, and it prohibits that.

Comment: yes, it's better to clarify that it's the Amazon's variant

Comment: "Amazon Keyspaces (for Apache Cassandra) appears as a nine-node, Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 cluster to clients and supports drivers and clients that are compatible with Apache Cassandra 3.11.2."

Comment: Amazon Keyspaces is basically a DynamoDB with CQL support, it doesn’t matter how it appears... There are a lot of limitations and differences. Similarly to Azure CosmosDB implementation, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229873/discussion-between-cristi-s-and-alex-ott).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This example works for me as well. I used katakoda to run this.
This is part of query.

Comment: Please include code as text rather than images