# Using two columns as primary key. Can I keep one column empty?

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I have a requirement where I need to uniquely identify a row based on two columns.

```
 nType | dType | severity
------+-------+----------
  down | 6500 | CRITICAL
```

Combination of `nType` and `dType` should always be unique. So, I created a table using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS severitymapping(nType text, dType text, severity text, 
PRIMARY KEY (nType, dType);
```

But there can be a case when dType is empty. So, that too is unique for my business logic. But database will not allow empty/null value of dType in the database.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd be very wary of using two Text columns as your primary key, as this will also be your clustering key and it is not a good candidate for that unless it is a small table with very few writes (which it may well be based on the description). You may be better off adding a surrogate auto increment column as your primary key, then defining a unique constraint on ntype and dtype. [Example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sVLraKXBvKRp1ndyu6z8p/0)

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL only (the question is MySQL-tagged).

---

Primary key expression cannot include NULLable columns.

If you need some column value to be NULL (not "empty" - there is no such term in SQL) then you cannot create PRIMARY key which includes this column. But you may create UNIQUE index - it allows NULLs. In this case you need in another expression to be primary key - autoincremented synthetic PK is reasonable.

Also the datatype for each column must be reasonable - the values shown and TEXT datatype does not match this. VARCHAR for `nType` and INT for `dType` looks like more suitable.

And TEXT column cannot be used in the index without the indexed prefix length specified.

So use something close to

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS severitymapping(
    nType VARCHAR(255), 
    dType INT, 
    severity TEXT, 
    UNIQUE (nType, dType),
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to have a `null` or empty value for any of the columns in a primary key in Cassandra.

The partition key (`nType`) uniquely identifies the partition and its hash value determines the node on which it is stored.

The clustering key (`dType`) uniquely identifies a row within a partition. Without it, it is not possible to store the row in the partition because the row cannot be retrieved without the clustering key. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are keeping `nType` as the partition key and `dType` as the clustering key.

> Cassandra does not allow null clustering key values.

> If you really need "no value" for some reason, then use an empty string OR some other special literal value like 'UNDEFINED' to cluster those together.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963248/how-can-i-have-null-column-value-for-a-composite-key-column-in-cql3) can help you too.